# Modify WatchKit Table View to prevent pushing interface out of view

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I am developing a stopwatch app for Apple Watch similar to the one that is preinstalled on the Apple Watch by default.  I want to have a lap table similar to the preinstalled one that can scroll but doesn't push the control buttons outside of the user's view.  Right now after I lap enough times, the stopwatch controls no longer be become accessible to the user without scrolling down.  Is there any way to make the WatchKit Table view scroll in place by turning the digital crown and display say 3 entries at once without pushing the rest of the UI below the screen?  [image: With one cell][image: Cells push controls off of screen][image: My table view settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in watchKit the tableViews scroll all the way out of the screen if they don't fit in. What you can do is

1) have the fourth tableView cell as a disclosure indicatory like this "V" while hiding the cell prior to the recent 3 and when this is clicked load the rest of the cells and have an extra cell to display "^" when all the cells are display . Clicking this will hide them back to the recent 3.

2) Navigate from the fourth cell to a new Interfacce controller displaying all lap data.